# What's the proper terminology for the cumulative existence of a disease in a patient?

Tags: terminology

I'm looking for the medical term that refers to the cumulative time a patient has suffered from a particular disease. For instance, if Jane was diagnosed with diabetes when she was 42, and now she's 55, the [**insert word I'm looking for here**] of diabetes in Jane's case is 13 years. What's the proper word to use here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fox et al used "diabetes duration" and "duration of diabetes":

Fox, C. S., Sullivan, L., D’Agostino, R. B., & Wilson, P. W. (2004). The significant effect of diabetes duration on coronary heart disease mortality: the Framingham Heart Study. Diabetes care, 27(3), 704-708.

so it seems you could substitute "duration" in your sentence. More generally, "disease duration" is [common](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22disease+duration%22).

---

Trogdon & Hylands used "time since diagnosis":

Trogdon, J. G., & Hylands, T. (2008). Nationally representative medical costs of diabetes by time since diagnosis. Diabetes care, 31(12), 2307-2311.

(in your sentence you could easily use units with this, too, as in "Jane was diagnosed with diabetes when she was 42, and now she's 55, 13 years since diabetes diagnosis."